# How to implement New Media Storage API to store file in Android 11 and 12?

Tags: java, android, android-11, android-12

i am trying to store the video on Device Storage and showing video in app but android version like 10,11 and 12 it is showing error that not able to create folder in phone.

My Error

```
 java.io.IOException: Operation not permitted
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:317)
at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1006)
at com.pixeldev.videoapp.helper.DownloadManager.onHandleIntent(DownloadManager.java:90)
at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:78)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)`
```

My Code

[My code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMFIY.png)

Comment: You don't have to implement the Media Storage API, you simply have to use it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use Public Directory inside Folder Like..

```
File myDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "MyPublicFolder");
myDirectory.mkdir();
```